# Airflow: when on_success_callback execute a function with parameters

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, airflow

i want to execute a function with one parameter that I pass from a task.

Here's my function with state parameter:

```
def sns_notify(state):
    client = boto3.client('sns')
    if state == "failed":
        message = config.get('sns', 'message') + state
    else:
        message = config.get('sns', 'message') + state
    response = client.publish(TargetArn=config.get('sns', 'target_arn'),
                              Message=message,
                              Subject=config.get('sns', 'subject'))
    return response
```

Here's my tasks with state as param:

```
t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='Dummy-1', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
                   on_success_callback=sns_notify("ok"), dag=dag)

t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='Dummy-2', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
                   on_success_callback=sns_notify("failed"), dag=dag)
```

When i run the dag the function doesn't stop sending mails (for this exemple)

Comment: `response` line should be grupped with `else` I suppose. Add 4 spaces here and you should be done

Comment: it's something else, i just want to initialize the variable message with if,else.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't stop sending mails? Do you keep receiving emails until you kill the executor?

Answer (score 5):

Every time the DAG is loaded by airflow it will execute `sns_notify("ok")` because you are calling the function. You need to instead pass just the function pointer `sns_notify`, which will receive `context`. See docs: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html

`trigger_rule` relates to how dependencies tasks are executed so is not relevant to `on_success_callback`.

I'm not sure how to pass variables to this callback however - came here looking for answers!

Comment: I guess, you need to add your parameters to the `context` dictionary, which `on_success_callback` callable receives as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Hoju pointed out the exact error.

you can use functional programming to help solve this issue.

```py
from functools import partial
send_success_notification = partial(sns_notify, "OK")
t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='Dummy-1', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
                   on_success_callback=send_success_notification , dag=dag)

send_failure_notification = partial(sns_notify, "FAILED")
t2 = DummyOperator(task_id='Dummy-2', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
                   on_success_callback=send_failure_notification, dag=dag)
```